# update file path stored in DB

Tags: sql, replace

I have a ton of file paths for PDF files stored in a table that I need to update. In the example below, how do I replace the `\\OldPath\` while keeping the `Blah\Blah\SomthingOdd.PDF`?

```
\\OldPath\Blah\Blah\SomthingOdd.PDF

\\NewPath\Blah\Blah\SomthingOdd.PDF
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What about `replace()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE('<ColumnThatContainsPath>,'\\OldPath\','\\NewPath\')
From Table1
```

The way replace function works is, it will only look for "\OldPath\" string and replace it with "\NewPath\" string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

Comment: If you add more details about your table structure, etc. then I can update my answer based on it.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL Server, you can use below code

```
SELECT REPLACE('\OldPath\Blah\Blah\SomthingOdd.PDF','\OldPath','')
```

Comment: I've got about 400 records that all have different Blah\Blah\SomthingOdd.PDF paths.  How do i ONLY replace the \\OldPath with \\NewPath?